# Recursive tail elimination, Impacts Time?

Tags: c++, recursion, time-complexity, big-o, tail-recursion

I was reading about recursive tail elimination but my main question is still unanswered, does this method impact run time complexity?

If so can someone show an example or that there is no way it will impact time complexity?

Comment: you should understand that recursive tail elimination only cut down cost of function call, which should not be counted in time complexity.

Comment: Elimimating recursive tail calls turns recursion into a loop. That is, instead of O(f(n)) function calls, you get O(f(n)) loop iterations.